# Difference in predicted value using two different methods

Tags: r, regression, modeling, prediction, ratio

Take these two vectors:

```
points <- c(44, 36, 33, 33, 29, 28, 28, 22, 21, 20, 18, 15, 15, 15, 12, 12, 12, 11, 10, 10,  8,  8,  8,  8,  7,  7,  7,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  5,  5,  4,  3, 3, 2,  2,  2,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1)

hours <- c(137.000000,  58.450000,  92.250000,  94.750000,  80.000000, 100.000000,  33.750000,  48.500000,  70.500000,  76.500000, 43.250000,  90.750000,  33.000000,  13.750000,  16.250000,  27.250000,  30.830000,  12.000000,  68.000000,  34.000000, 13.250000,  32.250000,   9.750000,   4.083333,  18.000000,  23.750000,   4.666667,  31.750000,  11.750000,   4.850000, 10.866667,   4.166667,  14.000000,   6.166667,   2.000000,   7.750000,  11.100000,   4.750000,   1.750000,   0.250000, 1.000000,  12.000000,  13.000000,   1.000000,   0.250000,   5.250000,   5.333333,   2.166667)
```

I made this model:

```
lm(points ~ hours)

# Call:
# lm(formula = points ~ hours)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)        hours  
#     2.9530       0.2823
```

The model suggests that if I do 1 hour, I get 3.2353 points.

I have also calculated mean points per hour:

```
mean(points/hours)

# 0.839875
```

The ratio suggests that if I do 1 hour, I get 0.839875 points.

Why is there such a big difference in the number of points per hour predicted by each method? Or am I interpreting something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are not interpreting anything wrong except: if you want to take all the data into account when making your prediction, the difference you noticed isn't "big" at all.

What you have done is fit a linear model using two different methods. You can see from the following plot that the two different fitted models are quite different. So it is no wonder that their predictions do not agree.

```
plot(hours, points) 
z1 <- 2.9530 + 0.2823*hours
lines(hours, z1, col="red")
z <- mean(points/hours)*hours 
lines(hours, z, col="blue")
```

[image]

It is up to you to decide which one gives the better prediction, or whether some other method will be better. But you can see from the plot that their predicted values at 1 hour really aren't that different compared to their values for larger numbers of hours.

Answer (score 1):

The are a number of considerations to take account of.

You present two alternatives for the number of points after one hour:

1. 3.2353
2. 0.839875

Your first method is an OLS model that minimises the differences between observed and predicted points. It does this by using an intercept term. Therefore your first prediciton is actually a base of 2.9530 and then 0.2823 for each hour. You can force an OLS model to go through the origin, at the penalty of increasing the size of the residuals (and possibly biasing your model):

```
lm(points~hours-1)

Call:
lm(formula = points ~ hours - 1)

Coefficients:
 hours  
0.3269  

sum(residuals(lm(points~hours-1)))
[1] 78.61759
sum(residuals(lm(points~hours)))
[1] -1.104672e-14
```

So here the prediction is that each hour adds 0.3269 to the points.

Your second method does not have an intercept term, but also it does not take into account any deviation from the data points. It is highly influenced by outliers, particularly those with few hours. Furthermore, as you are calculating the average of a rate, the [harmonic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) is more appropriate:

```
1/mean(hours/points)
[1] 0.3563906
```

Which at 0.3563906 points per hour is much closer to the OLS estimates.